# Annotation on vertical arrow

Tags: fonts, arrows, mathtools, annotations

I am illustrating the relation between some formulas. I need to add annotations on the iff arrow to refer them later. I know it can be done with `\overset` like:

```
\[ A \overset{(1)}{\iff} B \overset{(2)}{\iff} C \]
```

But how can I do similar thing when I arrange the formulas vertically like this:

```
\newcommand{\viff}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\iff$}}}
\begin{gather*}
A\\
\viff\\
B\\
\viff\\
C
\end{gather*}
```

Simplly putting (1) and (2) by the arrow does work. The annotations should have smaller font.

Answer (score 1):

For both situations there are commands in suitable packages. For the first one, you may use `\xLeftrightarrow` from the `mathtools` package, and for the second one (or for both) the arrows from the `tikz-cd` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[ A \xLeftrightarrow{~(1)~} B \xLeftrightarrow{~(2)~} C \]
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[d,Leftrightarrow, "(1)"] \\
  B \arrow[d,Leftrightarrow, "(2)"] \\
  C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]